# Problem running Teleoperation Package

Tags: ros, kinect, dynamixel, pi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi..
I try to move ax12 dynamixel servo by using kinect in Skeleton Tracker Teleoperation Package for Mobile Robot..

http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Skeleton%20Tracker%20Teleoperation%20Package%20for%20Mobile%20Robot

I have launched skeleton.launch, tracker.launch, robotis.launch, dynamixels.launch but my servo motor don't move at all..

Do I have to add new node for subscribing skeleton joint and publishing it to my servo ?

Thanks for your time..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58515/problem-running-teleoperation-package/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I had the same issue which was solved by setting use real robot to true in the tracker_params.yml file. pi_tracker/params/tracker_params.yml

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Zab](https://answers.ros.org/users/4384/zab/) with karma: 20 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on 2013-03-19**:
Hi @zab

of course.. I have set use_real_robot to true in the tracker_params.yml file..
but My servo don't move.. -__- How could this problem solve @zab ??

**Comment by [Zab](https://answers.ros.org/users/4384/zab/) on 2013-03-20**:
Check the baudrate that is being used for robotis_params. Try 1000000.

**Comment by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on 2013-03-20**:
hi @zab

I found the problem in command_rate, tracking_rate, joint_controller_rate in tracker_params.yaml file.. :) it works fine..
Thanks @Zab.. for your time..